# How to draw Bézier curves with Quartz with a quality equivalent to the default implementation?

Tags: cocoa, quartz-graphics, bezier

I am  drawing Bézier curves with my own code. Basically, I am computing a large number of points which I join with a CGPath. But even with the same line width, I can't achieve the same quality as the default implementation. The edge of the stroke is a bit blurry due to anti-aliasing. The stroke is not bad looking, but I notice that on Apple rendering, the anti-aliasing looks different; the width of the antialiasing zone (where the pixels are neither of the color of the stroke, nor the the color of the background) is lesser.

Spying a little with Instruments shows that UIBezierPath's stroke spends some time in libRIP, but I can't find what it is exactly.

Comment: Interesting, please post comment when you found out more.

Answer (score 0):

I have drawn an ellipse myself, using sin, and cos operations. My ellipse looks as good as the original.

I know that there is a problem when drawing over an gradient. Is that the case in your case?

Answer (score 0):

If you're plotting a large number of points, you might be getting darker anti-aliasing edges because you're over-plotting. I can't find a good image online to describe it, but if you plot from A -> B and then A -> B again, both lines might generate, say, 30% gray partial pixels, which will then be blended together resulting in 60% gray.

You may not think you're doing that, but if you have a high density of points then you might be ending up with overlapping components (and especially if you are plotting separate line segments you'll have your capping etc. overlapping).

Probably worth posting some sample code and screenshots taken with Pixie or xScope so we can see what's happening.